# From list of pairs ((3 . #\J) (5 . #\Q)) to list of strings (("3J") (5Q)) in Scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

I have a list of pairs ((3. #\K) (5 . #\J)) ... and I would like to create a function in scheme that returns the list as this: ("3K", "5J")...
I've beeing trying but I cannot make it.
This is what I have.

```
;  The deckCards will contain the list of pairs;
;  The real Deck will contain the empty list.
(define (deck->strings deckCards realDeck)
  (let lenOfItem ([n (my-lenght deckCards)])
    (if (= 1 n)
        (list (card->string (first deckCards)))
        (append realDeck (deck->strings (cdr deckCards) realDeck))))
  )
```

I did try doing with cond but for some reason it doesnt return the list and it seems impossible to append the list to the realDeack before calling itself recursively.

Comment: There might be a typo in your question. In your example `'((3. #\K) (5 . #\J))` and not the correct `'((3 . #\K) (5 . #\J))` where the first element is a dotted pair instead of a proper list with a floating pint number `3.0` as first element.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an approach and it worked. Not sure if it good to use it. However, this prints all the strings from top to boottom in a new line... Will this matter? I think its because I have 48 elements.

```
(map (lambda (i) (card->string i))
       clubs)
```

Comment: Shorter: `(map card->string clubs)`